# PHP IDEs with visual designer - what are the options?

Tags: php, user-interface

I'm looking for a PHP IDE with an integrated visual designer (*).

These are the only ones that I've been able to find so far:

- [RadPHP](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/radphp)
- [CodeCharge Studio](http://www.yessoftware.com/products/product.php?product_id=1)
- [TurboPhp](http://www.turbophp.com/)

The first two are commercial products, and the last one is open source (unfortunately it seems that it's been abandoned since 2007).

So, are these the only PHP IDEs with visual designers? Are there any other options (commercial or free) worth considering?

(*) By "*integrated visual designer*" I mean:

- A tool that can be used to design the UI **visually**, withouth needing additional programs or having to leave the IDE.
- A tool that is smart enough about the design elements, so that if I click on one of such elements, it takes me straight to the code associated with it (for example, an event handler for a click on a button).
- Ideally, it should be a "two-way tool", meaning that if I make changes to the code that affect some graphic element, those changes get reflected accordingly (and vice versa). Borland tools used to have this feature in many of their visual development products, I'm not sure if that's still the case with the tools sold by Embarcadero Technologies.

---

*Please note*:

- I'm not looking for separate tools for coding and designing (I know that the UI can be designed with lots of different tools, but what I'm looking for is an integrated product).
- I'm not looking for an integrated previewer.
- I'm not looking for an IDE capable of handling HTML/CSS/etc (there are already plenty of those). I want a tool that allows me to design *visually*.
- There have been similar questions posted before on SO, and I've read them. I just want to make sure that I'm not missing any relevant products.

*Updates*:

- I have a good knowledge of HTML and CSS. I just want to be more productive, and hopefully spend more time developing code and less time designing user interfaces (@waiwai933)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, why not just learn HTML/CSS? They're extremely easy to learn and you get a lot more flexibility when you code it directly.

Comment: The only thing you're missing is my question :) Ok, seriously, thanks for your input, I'll update my question.

Comment: You sound like you're coming from Microsoft land. It doesn't work like that in other web platforms. There is no event handler for a button click in PHP; client side events happen in JavaScript, and we don't explicitly attach PHP code to UI elements.

Comment: @Dan : I understand what you mean, and like you say, client side events are triggered from the client side. I've developed several projects using the PRADO framework, where you basically can attach event handlers written in PHP to different UI elements, and those handlers are then triggered from the client side (by the user interacting with elements rendered in HTML). I don't know how it is with other frameworks, but at least in PRADO, that's the way it works, and that's what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, aren't there any other options...?

I think I will try RadPHP (the tool looks exactly like what I need, and besides it's really cheap).

Anyway, I just wanted to check if I was missing some other options.

Considering the lack of replies so far, I guess that --unfortunately-- the answers to my question are:

1. Yes
2. No

Comment: If this isn't the right answer and someone can provide a good one, I'll be more than happy to reconsider and choose another answer instead.

Comment: "it's really cheap" -> "New User €4,049.10 + VAT +€769.33 == Total:€4,818.43". Yeah it's cheap indeed :DDD I think I keep searching (or use notepad at the end of the day...)

Answer (score 1):

I've practically tried all of the major solutions, and it seems that ultimately, you'll need to design with Dreamweaver and code/debug with another solution like NetBeans.

I haven't spent too much time with RadPHP, which is the closest to a "complete" IDE, but it seems that in order to use the integrated designer, you'll need to create a "form", so there's a learning curve. You can't just import your existing PHP documents and have them work in the visual designer.

Other solutions like NetBeans (via Plugin) and RapidPHP have internal browsers, but they'll actually parse the PHP, which may not always be desirable.

Microsoft Expression Web 4 is not much different than Dreamweaver. That is, it's an IDE with a visual designer that supports PHP, but has weak intellisense (supports only super-globals and core functions) and there's no debugging supoort.

Dreamweaver CS5 has expanded PHP support such as code hinting (intellisense) for functions and classes you define as well as highlighting syntax errors, but still no support for debugging (from what I've found).

There just does not seem to be a true PHP IDE that has all of the capabilities you would find in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Neatbeans, WeBuilder, PhpEd

Take a look at these, you might find something interesting. Most of them support HTML/CSS/MySQL/PHP/JavaScript without leaving the window.

You can always start using DW (DreamWeaver) wich is very good in HTML/CSS.
The only problem is if the IDE is really good with HTML/CSS it usually sucks in PHP.
I almost never use the built-in HTML features...